# How to reference private bitbucket packages in requirements.txt when containerizing with Docker?

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile, requirements.txt

I'm working on some private python packages (`johnathan_prices`, `johnathan_predict`) and have them all installed to the same `site-packages` folder so they can call each other easily.

I install them in editable mode (`pip install . -e`) so that debugging is fast (but always commit and push changes to my private repo).

For example, `johnathan_prices` scrapes prices from yahoo finance and makes them available to other packages. E.g. `johnathan_predict` might do something like `df = johnathan_prices.load('AAPL')`.

I'm trying to create a docker image and first need to create a `requirements.txt` which should contain packages like `numpy`, `pandas` as well as my `johnathan_prices` and `johnathan_predict`.

How do I create a `requirements.txt` that will contain the 3rd party packages (`pandas`, `numpy`) as well as the SHA links to my local packages so that when my Dockerfile does `RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt` it can download all the packages to `site-packages`.

I am self-taught so it's possible that my question is ridiculous and far away from best practices, in which case any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you